# VPN Service without having to set up VPN server?

Tags: server, vpn

I want to have a VPN for my pc so people cannot see my IP address and know my location, but I haven't found out a way to do so?

If I can set up a free VPN server, let me know how, because I would like to have one!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use VPN and only want to surf from a different IP you can always setup SSH on your home computer and then log into that and run the browser on your remote machine.

Install openSSH:

`sudo apt-get install openssh`

Test your connection from within your local network:

`ssh -x <computers IP>`

Then run the command for your browser once you are logged in...

`firefox`

This will bring up firefox from the other computer with a secure connection between the two. Essentially you will be browsing from the other computer and all traffic will appear to be coming from the computer in your home rather than the computer you are actually on. This is not the same as a VPN but it may work for what you appear to be trying to do... and without having to setup a VPN server.

To access the computer from outside your local network you will need to open port 22 on your router/firewall and forward the traffic at that port to the machine at your home.

I use this when i am browsing the internet at a coffee shop in order to encrypt all of my browsing whether or not i am visiting a https site.

EDIT:
I think what you are looking for is a proxy service.
If you want to use a proxy service you can find those on the web (look in the comments).
To tell your Ubuntu install to use the proxy service do the following:

1. Go to `System Settings`
2. Select `Network` then `Network Proxy`
3. Under the `Method` pull-down select `manual`
4. Enter in the IP of the proxy you would like to use (see lists in link below)
5. Click `Apply system wide`

This will effectively route your traffic through the proxy which can be located anywhere in the world.

Comment: My goal is to appear as if I am from russia, basically not giving my real location. However I can do this, I would like to.

Comment: @Trevor you'd have to find a free VPN service on the internet that can do that, or you can try and find someone with a server in Russia with a VPN server set up on it.  To run a VPN server yourself, though, you'd need a server with an IP in Russia.

Comment: You can also use a simple proxy service like this: http://spys.ru/free-proxy-list/ru/